# How to show selected check box vendors on front end home page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

We have created Custom Post "Product" and Custom taxonomy "Manage Vendors".
In Manage Vendors section add custom check box "Featured Vendor" for grouping of featured product using ACF,and assign to manage vendors.
now when we add a vendor there is an option for mark featured vendor.The problem is how to generate a loop for display selected vendors on home page.

Comment: Hi - I've answered using custom fields, as you say you're using ACF, but re-reading your question I wonder whether ACF is irrelevant?  Are you using a custom field or a taxonomy term?

Comment: Hello Andy,
We use Custom taxonomy "Manage Vendors". In Manage Vendors taxonomy advance-custom-field "featured" check-box added for grouping of product.

Comment: I'm still not certain how this is stored in WP - do you know if it's a standard taxonomy term, a custom field or something peculiar to ACF?

Answer (score 0):

ACF is a third-party plugin and I don't know what functions it gives you that you could use.

In general, though, you can create a query for posts with a particular custom field and value.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'   => 'featured', // must match the key that ACF has used
    'meta_value' => true, // must match the value that ACF has used
    'post_type' => 'product' // must match your post type
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then just run through a secondary loop as normal:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        // output html for each post here

    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Depending on what you want you could put this into your `front-page.php` template, hook it into `the_content` or turn it into a shortcode.